# A Gauss's third order modular equation.

Tags: special-functions, modular-forms

I would want a match for a typographical error (I think!). 
In a formula in the work  of “CARL FRIEDRICH GAUSS, WERKE BAND III.  GÖTTINGEN 1866” ([www.archive.org](http://www.archive.org)).

In chapter “ZUR THEORIE DER TRANSSCENDENTEN FUNCTIONEN GEHÖRIG. [II.][7.]” at page 442 line 13, You read:

$$\frac {A} {a} =\frac {3t-t^{3}+T(1-3tt)} {3[T(1-tt)+t(1-TT)]}.$$

In  R.H.S. denominator, the plus sign must be minus as:

$$\frac {A} {a}=\frac {3t-t^{3}+T(1-3tt)} {3[T(1-tt)-t(1-TT)]}.\tag1$$

Question: Why?

Answer: The (1)-equation is a third order modular equation.

Setting

$$T^{2}=(1+p)^{3}\big(\frac {1-p} {1+2p}\big)$$

$$t^{2}=(1+p)\big(\frac {1-p} {1+2p}\big)^{3}$$

with

$$(1+p)^{4}=\frac {T^{3}} {t}.$$

Replacing in that equation we have

$$\frac {1} {m}=\frac {3} {3(1+2p)}$$

therefore

$$m=1+2p.$$

Of course the multiplier of third order equation is

$$m=\frac {a} {A}$$

and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ moduli of first and third degree are related with

$$p^{8}=\frac {\beta^{3}} {\alpha}.$$

Comment: There is another typo in the numerator. The $3$ is missing in $(1-3tt)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct version of the Gauss formula is

$$ \frac{A}a = \frac{3t-t^{3}+T(1-3tt)} {3[T(1-tt)-t(1-TT)]}. \tag1 $$

The formula an be simplified to get

$$ \frac{A}a = \frac{t(3-tt)+T(1-3tt)} {3(T - t) (1 + t T)}. \tag2 $$

There are at least six different formulas such as

$$ \frac{A}a = \frac{(2tT)^2-(t+T)^2}
{(tt-3TT)+tT(6-4TT)}. \tag3 $$

The generating function of [OEIS sequence A261320](http://oeis.org/A261320) is

$$ \frac{A}a = \frac{\theta_3(0,q^3)^2}{\theta_3(0,q)^2} = 1 - 4q + 12q^2 - 28q^3 + 60q^4 + \cdots.
\tag4 $$

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to write the coefficient 3.